# How to save data to custom table using custom model in magento2

Tags: magento2, model

I have a custom table and I have written a custom model for it too, but I am not able to understand how can I perform something like `Mage::getModel('')->setData()`. I have followed the required structure, created the Model class and specified the resource model and defined the collection class, I can retrieve the data in the admin grid. But, still I am not able to understand how can I make use of my model to `setData()` and `getData()`. Here is my controller, to which I am making an AJAX call and I want to save my data to my custom table.

`Rent.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mofosys\Fastcure\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory;

class Rent extends Action {

    protected $request;
    protected $_moduleFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, moduleFactory $moduleFactory) {
        $this->_moduleFactory = $moduleFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $model = $this->_moduleFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $model->setName($data['name']);
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data['name']);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

My models are in the following structure:

`|-Model
   |-ResourceModel
   |    |-Module
   |    |    |-Collection.php
   |    |-Module.php
   |-Module.php`

Now, I am not able to understand that how can I insert this data in the table from my controller using my custom model.

`Module/Model/Module.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException as CoreException;

class Fastcure extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->getData(self::name);
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        return $this->setData(self::name, $name);
    }
}
```

All of this, doesn't seem to work, please help me out here guys.

Comment: Add your code for more information, you can not use Mage::getModel in magento-2. You have to save data by object manager in magento-2.

Comment: In Magento 2 you get access to your objects by dependency injection. Then you can setData() in the same way you do in M1.

Comment: @S H Patel, I have updated my code, please let me know how can I save my data to the custom table from my custom model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most simple solution for your own model is to get factory using di and then create 1 copy (or load it), fill it in with data and save. Here is the example with the model called Module:

```
class Rent extends Action {

    protected $request;
    protected $_moduleFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, moduleFactory $moduleFactory) {
        $this->_moduleFactory = $moduleFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $model = $this->_moduleFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $model->load($data['id']);
        }

        $model->setData($data);
        $model->setName($data['name']);
        $model->save(); // now deprecated, but works fine if you have no repository
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data['name']);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to insert a new row

Comment: @AbhishekDhanrajShahdeo
this code will create a new entry, if an id hasn't been sent.

Comment: I had to use `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

Comment: It gives error like : "Controller\\Save\\moduleFactory does not exist\"

Answer (score -21):

If you want to insert data, you can try inserting Custom Query.

```
$this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

$themeTable = $this->_resources->getTableName('yourtablename');
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $themeTable . "(field1, field2) VALUES ('1', 'NameABC')";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: No, don't want to use direct queries at all.

Comment: Not Recommended.

Comment: never use object manager, it is considered bad practice

Comment: It looks like he is passing static queries with objectmanger :( which is very very bad for your site health.